# Div position fixed not working in Iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have Div in Iframe with position set as fixed but i am scrolling a main page , it is not working. i will appreciate on your help.

```
 <div id="mainDiv" class="scrolling"> 
   <iframe>
       <div style="position:fixed"> </div>
   </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: "It is not working" is not a question

Comment: The element will get fixed in regard to the viewport that the iframe establishes only.

Comment: You can't have content inside an iframe like that (I think).

Answer (score 0):

iframe has to be used this way:

```
 <div id="mainDiv" class="scrolling"> 
   <iframe src="url of the content">   </iframe>
</div>
```

and to position an element as fixed, you have to specify the left/right and top/bottom, otherwise it takes the value 0:

Example:

```
style="position: fixed; left: 100px; top: 200px;"
```

Answer (score -2):

Its usually recommended that you do these things in a seperate css file, but in this case try this:

```
<div style="position=relative;display=fixed;"></div>
```

that should work :)

Comment: `display` does not have a `fixed`.

Comment: I recommend you delete this answer!